# Angular material StaticInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design, angular-material

I am getting below error in my browser console when I launch my Angular 5 page in browser.

> ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent ->
>   MatDialog]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent ->
>   MatDialog]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog!
>       at _NullInjector.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js._NullInjector.get

What am I  missing?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This error usually occurs when the service you are trying to use has not been provided in your `@NgModule`.

To use the `MatDialog` service, you will need to go to your module file and add `MatDialogModule` to the array of imports:

```
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MatDialogModule]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

You can find the import along with more information on how to use the dialog here: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api.

Comment: Notice that MatDialog isnt a component, is a service. Thats why the error is related to a provider message, as the MatDialog provider wasnt found. Please rephrase your answer, as this error has nothing to do with components.

Comment: Good catch, a bit sloppy on my part -- fixed.

Comment: This error is so bad as it says nothing about what you did wrong - and that is basicly configuration issue. IMHO good candidate for static code analisys - if you inject @Injectable class, and its module has no providers - push error.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the following error also come when you want to hit API and at that time you need to check whether the api is right or wrong, check spaces as well when you set API.

`Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[LoginDialogComponent -> InjectionToken MatDialogData]:`

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an error, if no data is supplied with @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data: any. Try to provide a default data. Also The dialog component name should be in entryComponents in respective Module.

Answer (score -1):

try to declare outside the Constructor and initialize inside constructor

my code like this 
My Interface is below

```js
export interface DoctorDetails
    {
        UserId:number,
        DoctorId:number,
        FirstName:string,
        LastName:string, 
        Speciality:string,
        EmailId:string,
        PhoneNumber1:string,
        PhoneNumber2:string,
        CountryName:string,
        StateName:string,
        city:string,
        AddressLine1:string,
        HospitalName:string,
        PrimaryMark:number
    }
```

My Declaration and Initialization is like below

```js
export class DoctorDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  url:string="http://hospitalapi.com/api/doctor/GetDoctor/";
  doctor:DoctorDetails[];//Declare
  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,
    private http:HttpService
    ) { 
      const id =route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
      console.log(id);
      this.url = this.url+id;  
      this.doctor = new Array<DoctorDetails>();//Initialize
    
    }
```